# Hi, Is there any way so that i can make anything outside my fragment unclickable?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am not sure if there is any way to do it.
On my screen , i have a list of fragments on left side and on clicking any of the fragments, it gets displayed on the right side.
Is there any way so that if i select a fragment then touch event gets disabled outside the displayed fragment so that user cannot switch fragments.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really using a list (`ListView`), then I have to assume you're also using an Adapter (e.g. `ArrayAdapter`), if so you can just override

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false; 
}
```

of your `ArrayAdapter` and this will disable the list items from being selected.